# How to replace a disk which contains the CentOS6

Tags: lvm, mbr, mirror

I have a machine that contains a disk which one has CentOS 6 Installed.

In that disk, There are two partitions. One of them if mounted on /boot, and the second one is a PV for the rootvg.

I need to replace this disk. How to copy OS from one disk to another safely with no software like Acronis or Symantec Ghost?

Comment: Are the disks of the same size? What partition table are you using?

Comment: Yes, the size is the same. There are two partitions: An ext4 partition mount on /boot and another one is a PV, from rootvg. Inside rootvg, I have LVs for root ("/") and swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of the disks are the same, you can copy the whole disk.

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```